# Erro ao instalar o PHP - "The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing"

Tags: php

Quero aprender PHP, mas nem instalar eu estou conseguindo.

Estou usando [esse tutorial](http://www.schoolofnet.com/2015/04/como-instalar-o-php-no-windows-do-jeito-certo-e-usar-o-servidor-embutido/), mas quando dou o comando `php --version` no prompt, aparece a mensagem de erro:

> The program can't start because MSVCR110.dll is missing.

Ficaria grato se alguém puder me ajudar.

Comment: Baixa a dll  `MSVCR110.dll` e coloca dentro da pasta do programa que vc esta tentando iniciar, esta faltando esta dll.

Answer (score 3):

Obrigado Dener.
Baixei o programa no https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
É só escolher a versão baixar e executar, depois disso funcionou normal, precisei fazer mais nada.

Answer (score 1):

Muitas pessoas ao instalar **WampServer** se deparam com um erro na hora de iniciar o aplicativo dizendo que está faltando o arquivo `MSVCR110.DLL`.

Esse erro, na verdade, é originado pela falta de uma biblioteca indispensável para rodar diversos aplicativos do Windows, e a solução para tal problema é muito simples. Basta fazer o download do [Visual C++ Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) e instalar.

Será mostrada a tela (como mostra na imagem abaixo) de download no qual é necessário escolher o idioma (pode deixar em inglês pois não há tradução para este pacote) e clicar em [**DOWNLOAD**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer aprender PHP, sugiro que não perca tempo tentando instalar o PHP e o servidor Apache manualmente, utilize uma ferramenta que já vem tudo pronto, assim você se foca em desenvolver e aprender a linguagem.

Não se preocupe em instalar manualmente, até porque quando for usar em um ambiente de produção, como se trata de PHP, é *quase certeza* que irá rodar em Linux, pois o custo dos servidores é mais barato e também porque se fosse pra rodar com Windows você poderia utilizar ASP.NET. Não que isso seja uma regra, mas é o que a maioria do mercado segue.

Aqui tem duas ferramentas que eu uso e recomendo, você não precisa ter as duas, escolha uma e teste.

## UwAmp

Servidor com Apache, MySQL, PHP e SQLite, ele é portátil, pode salvar em um pendrive e já funciona, e também já vem com o phpmyadmin configurado.

http://www.uwamp.com/en/

## Wamp

Ele é basicamente a mesma coisa que o UwAmp, porém conta com algumas ferramentas a mais e é mais robusto, pode rodar como serviço no Windows.

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Vale ressaltar que ambos não são recomendados para um ambiente de produção, apenas teste e desenvolvimento.